# Why can't I see any Need for Speed: Hot Pursuit 2 servers in Gameranger?

Tags: gameranger, need-for-speed-hot-pursuit-2

I am having a problem seeing servers for NFS: Hot Pursuit 2. I click 'Join' in Gameranger, the game starts, I go to multiplayer->LAN games but there is no games created.

But in Game Ranger list I can see a few players playing, with green lights near their nicknames.
I also check public internet games - there also are no servers shown.

how do I fix this, what do I need to check?

Comment: Did you install the game via Steam?

Comment: @Ahkam - no, I didn't

Comment: Is there an option besides "LAN games"?  LAN is Local Area Network; and is meant for playing on the same network, not online.

Comment: @JMac - don't know, this game does not start anymore on my machine, do not know how to fix it.